# pass an expression to a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code from a javascript book and the callback seems to be passed an expression as an argument. Is that the case or am I seeing this wrong? I didnt know, even though it works, that that was possible.

```
function multiplybytwo(a,b,c,callback)  {
  var i, ar =[];
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)  
  {
    ar[i] = callback(arguments[i]*2);  
  }
  return ar;  
}  

function addone(a)  {
  return a+1;  
} 

myarr =multiplybytwo(1,2,3,addone);
```

Comment: No, you're not seeing this wrong, you can pass functions to other functions as arguments. (I suggest you grab a lambda calculus book if this seems weird.)

Comment: Calling a function and passing an expression as an argument is pretty standard in every language that I'd care to use - it's not just a JS thing. The expression is evaluated and the _resulting value_ is passed to the function. Note that even something simple like `someFunc(1)` is passing an expression to a function, it's just that the expression is a simple number, `1` - but you can put pretty much _any_ expression, including things that call other functions, e.g., `someFunc(someOtherFunc(x*2) / 7 + (aThirdFunc() ? 1 : -1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
callback(arguments[i]*2);
```

is equivalent to

```
var a = arguments[i]*2;
callback(a);
```

Same as `callback(1+2);` to `callback(3);`

Answer (score 0):

The callback is passed the result of that expression.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are evaluated before they are passed to functions.

```
function foo( a ) {
    alert( a );
}

function bar( ) {
    return 1;
}

foo( bar( ) );
```

The above ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/AT9JK/)) will display 1.